# Why the code below is printing an extra-zero in the output?

Tags: python, format

I'm making a launch countdown (from 10 to 0), but after the "10" is printed, instead of printing "9", "8"... it ends printing "90", "80", "70"... with an extra zero.

Code below:

```
import time 
contag = 10 
while True: 
        print("Launch in:", contag, end="\r") 
        contag -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if contag == 0: 
               break 
print()
print()
print("Liftoff!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs, because when you use "/r" in the print statement `print("Launch in:", contag, end="\r")`

It replaces the current string on the line, with the new string, but as the string isn't the same length as the new string,

the 0 from the 10 from the first value, never gets replaced,

as such, to fix this mistake, all you need to do is add a `" "` after `contag` in print `print("Launch in:", contag, " ", end="\r")`.

```
import time 
contag = 10
while True: 
    print("Launch in:", contag, " ", end="\r") 
    contag -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if contag == 0: 
            break 
print()
print()
print("Liftoff!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you start printing `10`. After that you just overwrite the `1` on the console. You can easily fix this by adding an extra space to the print command:

```
print("Launch in:", str(contag) + " ", end="\r")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first message printed is this:

```
Launch in: 10
```

The `\r` tells the cursor to return to the beginning of the line, but *it doesn't erase the text that has already been printed*.

Then the second message printed is this:

```
Launch in: 9
```

The second message is one character shorter, so the `0` remains as leftover text from the first message.